# The simple 2000 coin toss simulator shows more than 2000 results

Tags: c

I need to do a coin toss simulator. This is the code I've done but it gives results more and less than 2000. Even if I increase the number of loop it gives close to the number but not exact. Every time the results change and there is no specific pattern. Whats wrong with this can you help me ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rand_coin();     

int main (void) {

      int heads = 0;  
      int tails = 0; 
      srand(time(NULL)); 
      heads = rand_coin();
      tails = rand_coin();
      printf("Heads = %d, Tails = %d\n", heads, tails);
      return 0;
} /* end main */

/* implement rand_coin() below: */

int rand_coin() {
    int value; 
    int i; // 
    int tails = 0;
    int heads = 0; 

    for(i=0; i < 2000; i++)        { 
        value = rand() % 2;  
        if (value == 1) {   
            heads++;
        }
        else {
            tails++;
        }
    }
    return heads;   
}
```

Comment: As the answer below indicate, readers feel that your expectations are incorrect. Could you explain what makes you think that there are more (or less) than 2000 results? If you actually flip a physical coin 10 times, how many heads do you expect? If you do that twice, do you expect the two results to add up to 10?

Comment: @Yunnosch Hi, If you flip a coin 10 times you get 10 results either heads or tails. for example, I was getting 964 heads 951 tails. which is less than 2000. If you flip a coin x times you can get x results. If I'm mistaken please correct me. Thanks for your answer

Comment: In the first set of 2000, code reported 964 heads.  In the **next** 2000 flips, code reported 951.  It is reasonable that the the 2nd sets of 2000 flips is independent of the first 2000 flips.

Comment: By calling `rand_coin()` twice, you're flipping the coin 4000 times. What your program is reporting as `heads + tails` is actually `heads + heads` for the two separate runs. It will often be close to 2000, but rarely will it hit *exactly* 2000.

Comment: I meant to flip a coin 2000 times and print out the results number of heads and tails. It's just a once when the coin is flipped 2000 times. if I expressed myself in wrong way sorry.

Comment: @billthelizard oh sorry didn't know that. I meant to flip it 2000 times only.

Comment: I thought when I call the function rand_coin i next to the tails i could get the number of tails on that function.

Comment: You might care to notice that your code (or, rather, the code provided by your tutor) does declare `rand_coin()` before using it, but it does not give a prototype for it. To give a prototype, you'd need `int rand_coin(void);`. In C++, the rules are different. It's a good idea to make the declaration and definition agree; it's also a good idea to make functions static until there's a second source file that needs to reference them — and then the declaration should be moved to a header and made non-static. (The `main()` function has to be referenced by the startup code; it is always non-static.)

Comment: The significance of the 'no prototype' is that you could write `rand_coin(3.14159);` and `rand_coin("squelch");` in the `main()` function and the compiler wouldn't complain — it doesn't have a prototype to validate the calls against.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you so much for this information. In the skeleton code there is a line "int rand_coin();     /* prototype for rand_coin function */".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  tails = rand_coin();
```

is wrong from an algorithmic point of view. You just need to use:

```
 tails = 2000 - heads;
```

---

I would suggest the following improvements:

1. Pass the number of tosses to `rand_coin` so that the number 2000 is not hard coded in multiple places.
2. There is no need to keep track of `tails` in the function.

Here's an updated version of your posted code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rand_coin(int num_tosses);

int main (void) {

   int heads = 0;
   int tails = 0;
   srand(time(NULL));
   int num_tosses = 2000;
   heads = rand_coin(num_tosses);
   tails = num_tosses - heads;
   printf("Heads = %d, Tails = %d\n", heads, tails);
   return 0;
} /* end main */

/* implement rand_coin() below: */

int rand_coin(int num_tosses) {
   int value;
   int i; //
   int heads = 0;

   for(i=0; i < num_tosses; i++){
      value = rand() % 2;
      if (value == 1) {
         heads++;
      }
   }
   return heads;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help now i got it.

Comment: @Nouman, you're welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 6):

Your `rand_coin()` function flips 2000 coins and returns the number of heads that appear. Your `main` function calls that twice, independently. There's no reason to think that the result will be exactly 2000.

You only need to call the `rand_coin()` function once to get the number of heads, then subtract from 2000 to get the number of tails.

```
heads = rand_coin();
tails = 2000 - heads;
printf("Heads = %d, Tails = %d\n", heads, tails);
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the example you gave in a comment:

> If you flip a coin 10 times you get 10 results either heads or tails. for example, I was getting 964 heads 951 tails. which is less than 2000. If you flip a coin x times you can get x results.

If you read your code with reference to that example the following happens:

You flip a coin 2000 times and get 964 heads and 1036 tails, for a total of 2000; but you only make the 964 heads visible by returning them from the function.
Then you flip a coin 2000 times again, and get 951 heads, not tails and 1049 tails, for a total of 2000 results.

Counting totals you have 1915 heads and 2085 tails, for a total of 4000, which equals 2*2000. Each of the two calls has generated 2000 results and reported only part of that as heads, correctly.